# How to handle the following exception- 'PngStream' object has no attribute 'chunk_eXIf'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a `CNN` with 8 hidden layers and coding the same in `Keras` with `Tensorflow` backend. While executing I am getting an unknown error: `'PngStream' object has no attribute 'chunk_eXIf'`.

I tried searching on google for the same error. only 3 links showed up! none of them are helpful.

```
#Importing
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

#classifier
classifier = Sequential()


#convolution layer-1
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 9, padding='same', input_shape = (128, 128, 3), activation = 'relu' ))
#maxpooling layer-1
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None))

#convolution layer-2
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, padding='same', activation = 'relu' ))
#maxpooling layer-2
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None))

#convolution layer-3
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation = 'relu' ))
#maxpooling layer-3
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None))

classifier.add(Flatten())

#full connection
classifier.add(Dense(1028, activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))

#compiling
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

#preprocessing
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

#loading images
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                                   r'D:\ImageDataset\Training',
                                                    target_size=(128, 128),
                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                    class_mode='categorical')

#training begins here
classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=7594,
        epochs=5)
classifier.save('cnn_four_classes.h5')
```

All epochs should be run without error since no image in my training data is .png! I have all .jpg.

Thanks

Comment: Keras used Pillow lib in background to generate data. This error comes from there. Check here https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/3558

Comment: @AnkishBansal Do I need to reinstall a stable version of pillow(I am using latest one). If possible, can you more specific on what changes am I suppose to make in the code. Thank you in advance. :D

Comment: You don't have to reininstall, this occurs only on window, that's weird. I'm not sure, how it can corrected? I used some alternative, when this occured. Maybe someone else, will help you.

Comment: @AnkishBansal If possible can you feed me with the working alternative? It would be like the biggest help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [nice-script](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly), by which you can control the inner process. It means, you can define your own way of generating data in each iteration, along with flowing data from directory.

In this scripts, author has load data from **.npy** file, while you need to read an image which can be done by **matplotlib**, **CV** or another package. Use it per your choice. Then add function you want to use for **augmentation**, such as rotation, zoom, shearing etc.